# Calling Excel sheet macro from C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, automation

I'm able to call a vba Excel module function from my C# program, **but I need to call a worksheet private function**. Anyone know how I would do that?

Module function call that works:

```
oExcel.Run("AppTitle");
```

I tried the following to try and call a worksheet function with no luck:

```
oExcel.Run("ProcessUnits.cmdRunSim_Click");
```

Comment: Isn't `Private` supposed to prevent exactly what you're trying to do?  You might be able to call it indirectly by adding a Public Sub which calls the Private method.

Comment: Yeah, but there are always ways around that stuff :) Like in .NET you can call a private function if you really wanted to with reflection.

Comment: I guess you could automate the Workbook's VBProject to edit the function, or add a Public sub which calls your private one.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: So I did add a public function inside a module to call this private worksheet but that didn't work. I had to change the function to public and then it worked. Still playing around with how to call this private one. The stub I make might have to be in the same worksheet as the private one instead of a module I'm guessing.

Comment: Yes - in the same sheet module as the Private method.

Comment: So I ended up creating 2 stubs. One in a module that already exists that will call the other which is public in the sheet that calls the private one I actually want to call. I guess that's a way around it :)